# Top-voted questions for the year?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics

This link shows the top-voted questions:

`https://mathoverflow.net/questions?tab=Votes`

In a New Year's spirit,
how can I restrict this query to top-voted questions posed in the year 2021?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When searching on the site you can restrict the search to posts created in some date range using `created:2021`. You can also search only for question if you use `is:q`. If you sort by votes you get [this as a result](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2021%20is%3aq). (You can use `is:a` to [get the answers](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2021%20is%3aa) posted in the given range.) And of course, you can add other restrictions, just as in any search. For example, you can restrict this to [one specific tag](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2021%20is%3aq%20%5bmg.metric-geometry%5d) or you can use `intags:mine` to display [only questions in your watched (favorite) tags](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2021%20is%3aq%20intags%3amine). See also [advanced search](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/search) and [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/searching).

Alternatively, you could use [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info). Here is a query showing [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537000/top-posts-between-two-dates?types=1), [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537000/top-posts-between-two-dates?types=2) and [all posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537000/top-posts-between-two-dates?types=1,2). (SEDE is only updated once a week, so the data for the whole year will be available after this Sunday.) SEDE also has a table PostWithDeleted, which has *some* information about deleted posts. But deleted posts are unlikely to get among the top voted questions. Here is the same query [restricted to deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537001/top-deleted-posts-between-two-dates). (It goes without saying that these queries can be modified and improved in many different ways. E.g., you can add restrictions by tag, look at the posts of a specific user, etc. It is also possible to create queries that look at *all* sites in the network: [top questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1537006/top-posts-between-two-dates-networkwide?minscore=50&types=1), [top questions excluding SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1537009/top-posts-between-two-dates-networkwide-not-so?minscore=50&types=1).) As a bonus, I will add a query showing [hot network questions from this year](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1075210/questions-which-were-in-hnq-between-two-dates?Date1=2021-01-01&Date2=2022-01-01) and a query showing [bounties from this year](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/962782/bounties-with-users-between-two-dates?Date1=2021-01-01&Date2=2022-01-01). (And I will also remind that such questions are listed also [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/70737/listing-bounties-and-hnqs).)

The search options described above work the same [on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2021%20is%3aq). Similarly, SEDE queries can be run [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1537000/top-posts-between-two-dates?types=1) as well.

---

I should probably add one important caveat - the posts made in 2021 are still gaining votes after that. The searches and queries mentioned above look at the total score - that includes also votes cast after 2021.

Using SEDE, it is possible to look at *votes cast in 2021* rather than *posts created in 2021*. Here are the [top questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537210/top-votes-posts-only-votes-cast-between-two-dates?types=1) and [top answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537210/top-votes-posts-only-votes-cast-between-two-dates?types=2). We can see from those queries that there are also some older posts which are still getting a lot of votes. If you want to have a look at posts before 2021 with most votes from this calendar year: [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537217/top-votes-posts-only-votes-cast-between-two-dates-restriction-on-posts-creati?types=1), [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1537217/top-votes-posts-only-votes-cast-between-two-dates-restriction-on-posts-creati?types=2).

---

It goes without saying that you can change parameters in the searches and in those SEDE queries to look at other years or completely different timespans.

Comment: And since we're playing around with various 2021 stats, here is a query showing [top comments in 2021](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1542871/top-comments-between-two-dates).