# How to find highly upvoted comments?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, searching

My question is simple: is there a way to find the most highly upvoted comments on mathoverflow?

Comment: I think that the tags ([meta-tag:comments]) and ([meta-tag:searching]) are suitable here - so I added those two tags. I included ([meta-tag:support]), too - but feel free to remove that one if you think that it does not fit. For example, if you think that the question should be understood as a request for a new functionality (in the other words, if you're not satisfied with the existing possibilities).

Answer (score 8):

This seems like something where [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) could be used as a suitable tool. Using the SQL syntax you can find top comments in the `Comments` table - and you can add various additional conditions. Keep in mind that the database is updated only once a week - so the most recent comments might not be there yet.

Various parameters in the queries linked below can be changed - number of top comments to be displayed, userid, tag name, ...

- Top comments ordered by score: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1418825/comments-with-highest-score), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1418825/comments-with-highest-score?num=500) (The same query was [mentioned in the MO chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2021/7/30).)
- Top comments ordered by score - with some additional information about the question: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1631601/top-comments-including-the-information-about-the-tags), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1631601/top-comments-including-the-information-about-the-tags)
- Top comments by a specific user: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1631597/top-comments-by-a-specific-user?num=500&userid=1532), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1631597/top-comments-by-a-specific-user?num=500&userid=1532)
- Top comments by a specific user who has deleted their account: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1631607/top-comments-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1631607/top-comments-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072)
- Top comments under questions/answers in the given tag: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1631599/top-comments-under-questions-answers-in-the-given-tag), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1631599/top-comments-under-questions-answers-in-the-given-tag?tagname=feature-request)
- Top comments posted between two dates: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1631606/top-comments-from-the-given-date-range), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1631606/top-comments-from-the-given-date-range)
- You can run the same queries for other sites in the network - simply switch the site in the SEDE interface when viewing the query. Here I included links for MathOverflow and the corresponding meta. It is possible to write a query that checks [all sites in the network](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1440256/comments-with-highest-score-multisite). Not surprisingly, it is dominated by Stack Overflow - being the largest site. Here is a [query which excludes SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1440257/comments-with-highest-score-multisite-not-so).

You can have a look at similar questions on other sites - but the solutions posted there rely mostly on SEDE, too. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177222/view-a-users-list-of-comments-sorted-by-score/177224#177224) suggests that one could alternatively use Stack Exchange API to show top comments by a specific user. I am not sufficiently familiar with this tool to check whether something similar could be used to get all high-scoring comments (and to modify it to get a better format.)

- [What is the most upvoted comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33931) (Mathematics Meta)
- [View a user's list of comments sorted by score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177222) and [Can I view a list of my "great comments", perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130906) (Meta Stack Exchange)
- [Is there a way to check voted comments?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6402) (Physics Meta)

Incidentally, not too long ago we had on this meta a post asking for high scoring questions: [Top-voted questions for the year?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5204) Unlike for question/answers, (at the moment) there isn't a way to search among comments built-in directly in the Stack Exchange software. See: [Searching for comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3247) and [Are my comments searchable?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5188)

Comment: Very many thanks, Martin!